# Nginx - убрать слеш из адреса, если запрашивается не папка

Tags: nginx

Вся проблема в том, что если раскомментировать эти две строки, при запросе любой страницы я получаю ошибку 404. Хотя проверка на наличие папки это банально.

По сути, мне нужно, чтобы все страницы были доступны только без слеша в конце, кроме папок. А как оно внутри, меня не волнует.

```
#if (!-d $request_filename) {
  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
#}

index  index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `if` - это [зло](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).
2. Чтобы все страницы были доступны только без слэша в конце `rewrite` не нужен - это обычное поведение. Есть только один случай когда NGINX самостоятельно [добавляет слэш](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать конструкцию if внутри блока location, чтобы проверять наличие слеша в URI и делать перенаправление только в случае его наличия

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;

    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    # Конфигурация для обработки PHP
    # ...
}
```